# Qual melhor metodo e mais seguro de programar PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

Boas bem pessoal eu estou agora a mudar para PDO no php queria a vossa opinião para saber se o método que estou a programar e seguro e se estou a programar PDO da forma mais correcta pois vi na internet diversas formas de programar

**Codigo de exemplo de como estou a fazer**

```
<?php
$result_cat = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE menu='home' AND activo=1");
$row_cat = $result_cat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$result_capa = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM categorias_anexos WHERE id_mae='".$row_cat->id."' AND seccao='capa'");
$row_capa = $result_capa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>
```

**Conexao com o banco**

```
$host   =   "localhost";
$bd     =   "sabeonde_sabeonde";
$user   =   "[USUARIO]";
$pass   =   "[SENHA]";

try {
$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$bd.';charset=utf8', ''.$user.'', ''.$pass.'');
$conexao->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo 'Error : <br>' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Teste**

```
$result_capa = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM categorias_anexos WHERE id_mae = :row_cat      AND seccao='capa'");
$result_capa = bindParam(":row_cat", $row_cat->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result_capa->execute();
$row_capa = $result_capa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Comment: vou deixar para alguem colocar uma resposta mais completa, mas creio que o método correto é usar PreparedStatements -> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Relacionado: [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

Comment: Da forma que estou a fazer o fica vulneravel ao SQL Injection ?

Comment: Pode me dar uma exemplo de prepare para listar conteudo usando while ?

Comment: estou aqui a tentar fazer mas não estou conseguindo

Comment: Da forma que você está programando ainda é possível sim ataques de SQL Injection. O PDO não formata a sua query automaticamente, você precisa utilizar prepared statements. Veja um artigo bem legal [aqui](http://www.diogomatheus.com.br/blog/php/trabalhando-com-pdo-no-php/)

Comment: Já vi e fiz ai um teste que coloquei acima mas nao funciona o que pode estar errado ?

Comment: Acho que você quis fazer sua pergunta sobre  como se conectar ,mas falou sobre conceito de segurança '_'

Comment: Off: Recentemente procurei algum framework para PDO, achei este: https://github.com/usmanhalalit/pixie muito mais rápido, do que ficar escrevendo tudo na mão!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Melhor prática usando Prepared Statements:

```
$id = 5;
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meuBancoDeDados', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM minhaTabela WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

 ?>
```

Neste exemplo, estamos usando o método de preparo para, literalmente, preparar a consulta, antes de os dados do usuário forem anexados. Com esta técnica, o SQL Injection é praticamente impossível, porque os dados nunca são inseridos na consulta SQL em si.
Observe que, em vez disso, usamos parâmetros nomeados (:id) para especificar espaços reservados.

Foi executada a consulta, ao passar uma matriz, que contém os dados que devem ser vinculados a esses espaços reservados.

```
$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
```

Um suplente, mas perfeitamente aceitável abordagem, seria usar o método bindParam, assim:
Uma forma alternativa mas que é perfeitamente aceitável e que pode ser usada sem medo por quem quiser usar, é usar o método bindParam, ficando dessa forma:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Depois de chamar o método execute, existem diferentes maneiras de receber os dados: uma matriz (o padrão), um objeto, etc. No exemplo acima, a resposta padrão é: PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC, o que pode ser facilmente substituída caso seja necessário.

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

No código acima, especificamos que nós queremos interagir com o result set da melhor maneira orientada a objetos. Abaixo irei listar algumas das opções disponíveis para essa interação.

> - **PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC:** Retorna uma matriz.
> - **PDO :: FETCH_BOTH:** Retorna uma matriz, indexada pelo nome da coluna e 0-indexados.
> - **PDO :: FETCH_BOUND:** Retorna TRUE e atribui os valores das colunas no seu conjunto de resultados para as variáveis ​​PHP que estavam amarradas.
> - **PDO :: FETCH_CLASS:** Retorna uma nova instância da classe especificada.
> - **PDO :: FETCH_OBJ:** Retorna um objeto anônimo, com nomes de propriedades que correspondem às colunas.

Comment: Acabei pesquisando um pouco mais sobre o assunto e acabei usando da forma como citou e a melhor forma e melhor segurança dessa forma da maneira como estava a fazer o sql injection era facilitado

Comment: @CésarSousa, marque como resolvido.

Comment: Claro já esta peço desculpa foi esquecimento mesmo mas obrigado pela ajuda de todos PDO estou a gostar mesmo muito acho que e muito melhor

Comment: Com certeza, amigo. boa sorte nos estudos.

Answer (score 1):

O que você deve imediatamente começar a ser preocupar e se possível alterar em seus projetos são duas coisas:

1) não utilizar mysql_*, pois foram descontinuadas;

2) JAMAIS utilize em seus comandos (query's) concatenações de strings como você citou no exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM categorias_anexos WHERE id_mae='".$row_cat->id."' AND seccao='capa'
```

Esse é o ponto chave para um ataque via SQL injection já que o "atacante" pode por meio de `requests` injetar comandos diretamente em sua query, vai um exemplo:

Digamos que eu tenha uma query dessa forma:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = '".$login."' AND password = '".$passwd.'"
```

Dessa forma basta o "atacante" enviar para a variável referente o seguinte valor:

```
1' OR '1' = '1
```

Ou seja o meu comando original se tornará:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = '' AND password = '1' OR '1' = '1'
```

Sendo assim essa query será válida e irá retornar algo dela já que a cláusula 1 = 1 é sempre válida, ou seja, a brecha de segurança está feita.

A resposta para a questão como foi mencionado é o uso de `PreparedStatements`.

Sobre o seu exemplo de utilização, não é claro para mim o que sua função `$conexao->prepare` retorna, mas caso ela retorne uma `statement` a utilização seguinte vai estar errada e deveria ser:

```
$result_capa->bindParam(":row_cat", $row_cat->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```